# Java code to query websphere 8.5 user registry

Tags: authentication, registry, websphere, user-registration

I am creating a custom Websphere TAI (Trust Association Interceptor) class. Here I need to check if user actually exists and is active in websphere based application. 
For this I need to query Websphere registry.

Can someone give me Java code to do it ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are checking for the user within the user registry?  All you should have to do at the TAI level is set the user's ID and return it to WebSphere.  At that point, WebSphere should look up and populate the Principal for you based on the User Registry.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Virtual Member Manager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/prodovrview.html) if you have this component installed. [Here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/performingasearch.html) is how to perform a search.

If VMM is not installed, you have no option other than query underlying repository (quite likely LDAP) directly.